# How to get the 'list' name from the folder 'server relative URL'?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have the server relative URL to a folder in SharePoint. Hence, I can call `/GetFolderByServerRelativeURL(url)`.

How do I get the name of the list this folder belongs to ?

I need to use the list name to call the `/lists` endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to get the listname, one needs to query `/GetFolderByServerRelativeURL(url)/Properties` endpoint. This gives us the `listname` and/or the `list GUID`.

We can then call the lists endpoint like `/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')` and `/lists(guid'list GUID')`.